# how to access exoplayer methods inside recycler view adapter

Tags: java, android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have a exoplayer which plays videos. And i want to capture it current position.

So, in MainActivity

```
lateinit var player: SimpleExoPlayer

fun timeCapture(view: View) {
        Log.d(TAG,"${player.currentPosition}")
    }
```

is working fine

But, The fact is  need to capture this event on Recycler view adapter

in MainActivity i'm passing data to recycler view like this,

```
 var viewAdapter = MainActivityAdapter(data)
```

Since, `player` is lateinit i cannot access it in adapter like below

```
        Log.d("logger","${MainActivity().player.currentPosition}")
```

this gives error.

So, any suggestions for this

Comment: When do you want to capture this event?  any event like click item

Comment: You can pass the instance of ExoPlayer to your adapter MainActivityAdapter(data,exoplayer). Then use it to do whatever you want in the adapter class.

Comment: @AlphaOne i did that, but exoplayer i'm initializing on user selecting a video. So, in oncreate exoplayer is not initialised.

Comment: @naanu Okay. Do one thing, create a global variable and function to set that variable in the adapter class. Call that function when user selects the video like setPlayer(exoplayer)

Comment: @AlphaOne you mean singleton variable. How to that ?

Comment: I mean create a private variable in your adapter class and a function to set it's value if it is null and call this function whenever user selects the video passing the exoPlayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create a global variable that's all. And be careful to handle errors while using that.

```
GlobalVariables.kt

package com.company.notexist.model

import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer

object GlobalVariables {
    lateinit var player: SimpleExoPlayer
}
```

to access above `player` variable import it to any file

```
import com.company.notexist.model.GlobalVariables.player

then rest of the code is normal
...
player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this)
id_player_view.player = player
...
...
```

then in on adapter use it like this,

```
Log.d("logger","${player.currentPosition}")
```

***but don't forget import statement and error handling(i.e check for null and other things)***